# Extract by mask with grid shapefile in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, clip, vector-grid

I have a tiff file. I want to extract it by a grid but every shp cell should clip the tiff file to a new tiff file. Perhaps the attached image could make sense.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example use ModelBuilder with Iterate Feature Selection:

[image]
Each extraction is named by an attribute in grid feature class

Comment: That's works.. Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: Nice! Please accept my answer with the checkbox